# Search results lefthand filters are missing

Tags: search, navigation, hidden

When utilizing search the left hand filters are missing.  Is there a way to have left hand navigation appear for search results?  In all other instances we want quick launch/tree navigation hidden.  Thanks![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgRyU.png)

Answer (score 0):

The page you show has no results.  That left-hand menu contains "contextual" links, so what shows up there is dependent on what is returned in the search results.

That's assuming you are using the default page and have not modified the web parts.